# Screen not moving up after keyboard appears when user clicks on text field inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, keyboard

I have an iPhone application (Swift 3) where the content dynamically loads a Login from a CMS. The form contains fields where a user needs to enter and submit, nothing tricky.

Unfortunately, when the user clicks on the Login Field, the keyboard appears and it is hiding the UIWebView that is containing the form.

How am I able to resolve this?
[Please Check Screenshot, click the form hiding my UIWebView Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47B0s.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}


func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height/2
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: No solution? im implement your code but still show me same issue

Comment: ya sure wait will show you...but where i show you my code??

Comment: @AnkitKumawat u can add your code in your question itself...Its better to add so that others can see what u tried.

Comment: @Rahuld ya sure,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, This will work for **Swift 3**. In this case, I have given 4  textFields

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var textField4: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
  {
    view.endEditing(true)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      self.textField1.delegate = self
      self.textField2.delegate = self
      self.textField3.delegate = self
      self.textField4.delegate = self

      self.textField1.tag = 0
      self.textField2.tag = 1
      self.textField3.tag = 2
      self.textField4.tag = 3
     }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      switch textField.tag {
      case 0:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -120, up: true)
      case 1:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -140, up: true)
      case 2:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -160, up: true)
      case 3:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -180, up: true)
      default:
          print("Do Nothing...!")
      }
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      switch textField.tag {
      case 0:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -120, up: false)
      case 1:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -140, up: false)
      case 2:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -160, up: false)
      case 3:
          moveTextField(textField: textField, moveDistance: -180, up: false)
      default:
          print("Do Nothing...!")
      }
  }


  func moveTextField(textField: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool)
  {
      let moveDuration = 0.3
      let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)

      UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
      UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
      UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
      self.view.frame = (self.view.frame).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
      UIView.commitAnimations()
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry for that @Grecory Wilson Pullyattu you not understand my question, i use UIWebView and UITextField inside my Webview.....so how can i implement your code ???

Comment: You can add your textField any where else, and implement this code. it will work. but this code is for only 4 textfields. you can add more textfield also by add more case

Comment: my UITextField Inside UIwebview so how can i implement your code...why you not understand my recruitment...

Comment: Can you show me your viewController Scene screen shot of your storyboard